# os.path.join - can I get consistency between Windows and Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, filenames

I would quite like a set of filename components that will give me consistent and "nice-looking" filenames on both Windows and Cygwin. Here's what I've tried:

```
  Input                                Windows      Cygwin
1 os.path.join('c:', 'foo', 'bar')     c:foo\bar    c:/foo/bar
2 os.path.join('c:\\', 'foo', 'bar')   c:\foo\bar   c:\/foo/bar
3 os.path.join('c:/', 'foo', 'bar')    c:/foo\bar   c:/foo/bar
```

1 isn't what I want on Windows, I do want an absolute path, not relative to the current directory.

2 and 3 both work, but are not (I hereby define) "nice-looking" since they mix up forward and backward slashes on one platform or the other. My error and logging messages will be more readable if I can avoid this.

Option 4 is to define myself a `driveroot` variable equal to `c:\` on Windows and `/cygdrive/c` on Cygwin. Or a function taking a drive letter and returning same. But I'd *also* prefer to avoid per-platform special cases between these two.

Can I have everything I want (join identical path components, to give a result that refers to the same absolute path on both platforms, and doesn't mix path separators on either platform)? Or do I have to compromise somewhere?

[Edit: in case it helps, the main use case is that `c:\foo` is a path that I know about at configuration time, whereas `bar` (and further components) are computed later. So my actual code currently looks a bit more like this:

```
dir = os.path.join('c:\\', 'foo')

# some time later

os.path.join(dir, 'bar')
```

That's using option 2, which results in "nice" reporting of filenames in Windows, but "not nice" reporting of filenames in Cygwin. What I want to avoid, if it's possible, is:

```
if this_is_cygwin():
    dir = '/cygdrive/c/foo'
else:
    dir = 'c:\\foo'
```

]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on cygwin"? Are you running a special version of Python for cygwin?

Comment: @David: I'm running the version of python that Cygwin delivers via its package management. It's 2.6.5, built with whatever gcc version and options Cygwin uses to build its distribution binaries.

Comment: Use the native python syntax `join` along with `os.sep`... `os.sep.join(path_list)`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** David pointed out that my understanding of 'current directory' on Windows is wrong.  Sorry.  However, try using `os.path.abspath` to get nice pretty paths, or `os.path.normpath` if you don't need absolute paths.

In method 1,

```
os.path.join('c:', 'foo', 'bar')
```

The output, `c:foo\bar`, is correct.  This means the path `foo\bar` below the *current directory* on `c:`, which is not the same thing as the root directory.  `os.path.join` is doing exactly what you tell it to, which is to take `c:` (the *current* directory on drive c) and add some extra bits to it.

In method 2,

```
os.path.join(r'c:\', 'foo', 'bar')
```

The output for Cygwin is correct, because in Cygwin, `c:\` is not the root of a drive.

What you want is the `os.abspath` function.  This will give you the absolute, normalized version of the path that you give to it.

**However:** You won't get the same string on Cygwin and Windows.  I hope you're not looking for that.

Comment: I know that 1/Windows is correct as per the definition of what os.path.join does. All 6 are correct, I'm not claiming there's a bug in os.path.join. 1/Windows just doesn't refer to the file I want it to refer to, which is why `('c:', 'foo', 'bar)` isn't the input I'm looking for. So, `os.path.abspath` doesn't help me either as far as I can see.

Comment: Actually, there's no such thing as the current directory on C: in Windows. Each process has a single current directory.  The command line interpretor cmd.exe fakes things so that it appears that you have separate working directories for each drive letter.

Comment: And no, I don't want the same string on Cygwin and Windows, but I do want to choose a collection of inputs such that the result refers to the same file: in this case the file that Windows calls `c:\foo\bar`.

Comment: @Steve: why don't you just wrap `os.path.join()` with a function that would accept a drive letter component and other components as arguments, and will convert the drive letter to properly work with windows and Cygwin (even using /cygdrive/x/ if needed)?

Comment: @Boaz: Because that would involve code that checks whether it's running on Cygwin or not, and acts accordingly. There are a number of ways of computing the strings I want, but *this* question is whether `os.path.join` (or other related functions) can be coerced into doing it :-) I suspect Dietrich may have identified the fundamental issue when he points out that `c:\foo` is not an absolute path in Cygwin, it's just magicked up by the file libraries. Since Windows `os.path.join` is computing an absolute path, but Cygwin a relative one, perhaps it's impossible to reconcile them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

At work, I have to deal with pretty random combinations of Windows without Cygiwn, Cygwin with non-Cygwin Python, Cygwin with Cygwin Python, and Unix. I haven't found a way of coping with this stuff that I'm particularly proud of, but the least hateful approach I've found so far is to always use what Cygwin calls a "mixed style" path on Windows. That's a Windows style path, but with forward slashes instead of backslashes.  E.g., c:/foo/bar.txt. It also avoids a lot of gotchas, such as Cygwin bash shells seeing "\" as an escape character.  Sadly, this means missing out on a lot of Python's built-in path manipulation utilities and doing things the hard way.

I'm don't have access to a machine with Python and Cygwin on it ATM, so I can't test the code snippets below. I apologize for any errors...

```
    #Combine a path
    path = '/'.join([ 'c:', 'foo', 'bar'])

    #Split it back apart
    pieces = path.split('/')
```

When in doubt, try to call Cygwin's cygpath utility. A lot of weird edge cases pop up in Cygwin, such as the fact that /cygdrive/d/ == d:\ and yet /cygdrive/d/../../ == c:\cygwin (or wherever you have Cygwin installed).  Also remember that backslashes are used as escape characters in Unix style paths, such as /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings. Cygpath does an astonishing job of taking care of these, and if it's not available it's *generally* safe to assume that your weird edge cases don't exist.

```
import sys
import subprocess

#Buncha code here ...

#We got somepath from somewhere, and don't know what format it's in.
try:
    somepath = subprocess.check_output(['cygpath', '-m', somepath])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    #Cheap attempt at coping with the possibility that we're in Windows, but cygpath isn't available.
    if sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
        mypath = somepath.replace('\\', '/')
    else:
        mypath = somepath

#Now we can assume somepath is using forward slashes for delimiters.
```

Some Windows commands get confused if you pass them a Windows style path, and some Cygwin commands get confused if you pass in a Windows or a mixed style path. For instance, rsync can get confused by "c:/foo/bar.txt" because that looks like you're trying to specify "/foo/bar.txt" on a remote computer named "c". When you're calling one of these finicky Windows or Cygwin programs, use cygpath to make it happy. If you're calling a finicky Windows program and cygpath isn't available, try the ghetto "winpath = mypath.replace('/', '\')" approach. I think that can fail if you're converting a Unix style path and don't have Cygwin available, but hopefully if you don't have Cygwin available you don't have any Unix style paths on Windows to start with...

Comment: You're supposed to be using `os.path`, not hard coded path separators.

Comment: You're supposed to read the answer rather than just making a comment that is explained in the answer itself.

Comment: `cygpath` is a lifesaver when it comes to randomly cobbled together sets of software in Cygwin.